# Dynamic Allocation of two-dimensional array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array, allocation

Hi I'm pretty new to C++ and I need to dynamicacally allocate two-dimensional array. No error but in runtime when I set a order and first row then I get a runtime error: "Segmentation Fault"...Here's code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double ** allocateDynamicArray(int &order){
    double ** arr = new double *[order];
    for(int i = 0;i < order; i++){
            *arr = new double[order+1];
    }
    return arr;
}
void deallocateDynamicArray(double **arr, int order){
    for(int i=0; i<order; i++){
        delete [] arr[i];
    }
    delete [] arr;
}

void addAndPrintArray(double **arr, int order){
    cout << "Zadejte prvky pole radu " << order << endl;
    for(int i=0; i< order; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< order+1; j++){
            cout << "Pole[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i< order; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< order+1; j++){
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            if(arr[i][j] < 10 && arr[i][j] > -10){
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int order;
    cin >> order;
    double **dynArray = allocateDynamicArray(order);
    addAndPrintArray(dynArray, order);
    deallocateDynamicArray(dynArray, order);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're almost certainly better off using a `vector<vector<double>>`.  Much less complicated to work with, since there are no allocation/deallocation headaches.

Comment: `*arr = ` should be `arr[i] = `

Comment: Yeah but what if I want to use this? I just need to know what's bad in this code...

Comment: One reason why you shouldn't use this is that there is no check to see if new[] fails anywhere in that loop.  If it fails, you have a memory leak due to `new[]` throwing an exception.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to use this: `arr[i]` or rather always use vectors?

Comment: @PatrikŠtěrba - If you do need to use the above, use the second form in my answer.  The reason is that you can easily recover if `new[]` fails, as it isn't being called in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to increment `arr` in your initialization loop:

```
for(int i = 0;i < order; i++){
     *arr = new double[order+1];
```

Do this instead:

```
for(int i = 0;i < order; i++){
     arr[i] = new double[order+1];
```

Also, unless your going to change the dimensions of one of the rows, the method above is inefficient compared to this way of allocating a 2 dimensional array:

```
double ** allocateDynamicArray(int &order){
    double ** arr = new double *[order];
    int cols = order+1;
    double *pool = new double [order * cols];
    for(int i = 0;i < order; i++, pool += cols){
           arr[i] = pool;
    }
    return arr;
}

void deallocateDynamicArray(double **arr){
        delete [] arr[0];
        delete [] arr;
    }
```

Just two calls to `new[]` and only two calls to `delete[]` are needed, regardless of the number of rows and columns.

The other reason why the second form above should be favored over the first form is in the case where `new[]` may throw an exception.

Using the first form, if somewhere in that loop, `new[]` throws an exception, you have to keep track of all of the previous successful allocations, and "roll them back" by issuing `delete[]` calls.  Not nice.

Using the second form, if the first call to `new[]` fails, then there is no harm as the exception will be thrown without leakage (since no memory was successfully allocated).  If the second call to `new[]` fails, all you need to do is to provide (inside of a `catch` block) the deletion of the first call to `new[]`.

```
double ** allocateDynamicArray(int &order) {
    double ** arr = new double *[order];
    int cols = order+1;
    try {   
       double *pool = new double [order * cols];
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc& e)
    {
       delete [] arr;  // delete previous allocation
       return nullptr;  // or rethrow the exception here
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < order; i++, pool += cols)
        arr[i] = pool;
    return arr;
}
```

Note that `std::vector` does all of this work for you.  However if for some reason you can't use vector, and the two dimensional array will remain the same size throughout its lifetime, use the second form.

In addition, the second method lessens memory fragmentation of the heap.  Instead of `rows` calls to the allocator, only one call is made to the allocator to allocate the data.  If `rows` were, say 1,000 or 10,000, you see right away it is better to make 2 calls to `new[]` instead of 10,000 calls to `new[]`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want. :D

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
double ** arr = new double *[order];
for(int i = 0;i < order; i++){
        *arr = new double[order+1];
```

with

```
double ** arr = new double *[order];
for(int i = 0;i < order; i++){
        arr[i] = new double[order+1];
```

In your present code you initialize only first array element.