# Dynamic array cause system crash

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have constructor of a class, which whenever called causes crash of whole system(it becomes unresponsive). I figured out that this is caused during memory allocation for dynamic arrays.
Here is fragment of my code:

```
//constructor
ImageData::ImageData(string givenPath){
    imagePath=givenPath;    //path
    imageObject = imread(imagePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); //load Image
    chosenX = 0;            //default value
    chosenY = 0;            //default value
    cols=imageObject.cols;  //columns in image
    rows=imageObject.rows;  //rows in image
    size = cols*rows;       //amount of pixels in image
    startPoint = 0;         //default - top left corner

    //setup memory for dynamic arrays
    mapWithDistances = new int * [size];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ){
        mapWithDistances[i] = new int[size];
    }

    distances = new int [size];
}

//deconstructor
//deletes dynamic arrays
ImageData::~ImageData(){

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       delete [] mapWithDistances[i];
    }

    delete [] mapWithDistances;
    delete [] distances;
}
```

It might be trivial, but I'm unable to find a solution. Where did I make a mistake ?

Comment: `for( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ) mapWithDistances[i] = new int[size];`  What would you do if a `new` fails?  This code will have a memory leak.  Even if you knew what to do, you have to write code to do a `catch` and then deallocate all of the previous successful allocations.  Use container classes, or write the code using only 2 allocations (search SO on how to do this).

Comment: Your code will fragment the heap memory horribly.  If you're going to write code like this, see this alternate for allocating a 2-d array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425126/dynamic-allocation-of-two-dimensional-array-c/27425293#27425293

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to O(n^2).  Or O(n^4) depending if n is number of pixels, or diagonal of image.

You allocate an array of size (number of pixels)*`sizeof(int)` for each pixel.

A 1000 by 1000 pixel image has 1 million pixels.  If `int` is 4 bytes, then the above code allocates 4 trillion bytes.

This is a bit of a resource hog.

The solution is to not allocate 4 trillion bytes.

In general, when working with medium large n values, you have to keep the O-memory usage really close to linear, or jump through hoops.  This is more important than keeping your O-time down, because you can always get more time by simply waiting a bit longer: poor time performance means you wait, poor memory performance means you fail.

Comment: The weird thing is that when for example I'm setting manually size = 4, it still freezes the application(although I can stop debugging, without reset). I need to store information about differences between colors of pixels between each other. Is it really impossible to use array of size [10^6][10^6]?

Comment: @user3206986 - Your code is a heap fragmentation nightmare.  See my comment above for a link to how to do this in two allocations, not 1000 allocations.  You will find right away if you have enough memory, and not delay the memory exhaustion until you reach the middle of your loop.