# How to create a pointer to pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

The problem that I have is to create a specific matrix.

I have to use an array called for example `ptr` with `x` pointers. Each pointer in this array should point to a new array (in this case, an `int` array; each array is a new line in the matrix then).

All `x` arrays should be created with `new`; in the end, it should be possible to access the matrix with `ptr[a][b]` easily.

After a lot of trying and failing, I hope that someone can help me out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your attempt(s).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425126/dynamic-allocation-of-two-dimensional-array-c/27425293#27425293

Comment: Y U NO USE `std::vector` ?

Comment: @Quentin `I have to use a pointer **ptr`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I haven't saved any attempts, because there were too many fails (which wasn't smart from me, sorry for that). Thanks for your efforts, though!

Comment: @Quentin Unfortunately, I don't know what std::vector is (or how it works) and I am pretty sure that I'm not allowed to use it in this case, I'll keep it in mind for future programming though, thanks.

Comment: @Rinzler yeah, that was more of a cry of despair than an actual question. I don't understand that so many homework-only questions pop around, when they should be given to students with the corresponding courses.

Comment: @Everknow - Please see the link I posted.  Even though you accepted the answer that works, there are flaws with it that you should know about.

Comment: @Everknow please do ! An `std::vector` basically wraps a dynamically allocated array, and handles it properly. Saves a lot of headaches.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll have a deep look into it, at first sight it really seems helpful. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Quentin That's really good to know; seems to make things easier in this case, indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of pointers in the array is known, you could simply use a raw array of pointers to int:

```
int* my_array[10]; // 10 int*
```

Then you should allocate memory individually for each pointer in the array using usually a for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    // each int* in the array will point to an area equivalent to 10 * sizeof(int)
    my_array[i] = new int[10]; 
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't know the size of the array, then you need a pointer to pointers:

```
int** ptr_to_ptr = new int*[10];
```

Note that I am allocating space for 10 `int*` and not `int`.

Remember to deallocate the memory allocated above also for the internal pointers, once you don't need that memory anymore.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, everything's even accessable through ptr[a][b]. Now I got a better understanding of how this is working, thank you very much!

Comment: @Everknow No problem dude :) But I recommend you to have a look to other examples. This topic is not so obvious, and you need to read a good guide in order to understand it perfectly ;)

Comment: @Rinzler There are some flaws with this approach, even though it s used almost all the time to create a 2d array from a `T**`.  One flaw is that there is no recovery if a call to `new[]` throws an exception in the middle of the loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, it could throw, but for this situation I think it's enough. If you want to improve the answer, feel free to do it, and I am happy to learn new things.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is obviously homework, let me give you a better answer for *your* sake to go alongside the accepted one.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(10, std::vector<int>(10));
//                                   ^   ^                ^
//                Column count ______|   |________________|
//                                       |
//                                       |___ Each column is 
//                                            initialized with 
//                                            a vector of size 10.
```

That's a 10x10 matrix. Since we're using vectors, the sizes are dynamic. For statically sized arrays, you can use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you want. Also, here's the reference for [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).