# Copy char matrix (char**) without library functions

Tags: c++, matrix

I need to make a function as homework which given a char matrix composed of T and A returns the number of islands there are on said matrix, being T the land and A the water in Spanish. All this I could do yet there is one more problem, I can modify the matrix I was given as parameter. I thought of copying the matrix before calling my function and sending the new one but I could not do this. As the title says I need to to this with absolutely no library functions of any kind (e.g. strcopy). I'll pass my code just in case:

```
int islands(char** map, int col, int row){
char** aux = map;//I don't think this line does anything
int cont = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        char c = aux[i][j];
        if (aux[i][j] =='T') {
            cont++;
            deleteLand(aux, i,j, col, row);
        }
    }
}
int a = cont;
return cont;
}


void deleteLand(char** map, int t1,int t2, int col, int row) {
map[t1][t2] = 'A';
for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
        if (!(i==0 && j ==0)&&(t1 + i >= 0 && t1 + i < col) && (t2 + j >= 0 && t2 + j < row)) {
            if (map[t1 + i][t2 + j] == 'T') {
                int tc = t1+i;
                int tr = t2 + j;
                deleteLand(map, tc,tr,col,row);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And an example of what it returns:
Entry: (['T','T','A'
           'A','A','T'
           'A','A','A'
           'T','T','A'], 3, 4)
Returns: 2

Hope it is clear enough. Also, while writing this I realized I could save the value of the matrix when entering and copy it again on exit but I think it would be practically the same. Thanks a lot for any help provided

Comment: A matrix is commonly a synonym for a 2D array. Something like `char` is a "pointer to pointer to `char`". It cannot be used for such a construct. If you need a 2D array, use one: `int (*array2d)[COLS]`.

Comment: Wouldn't that give me just one of my rows?

Comment: @BrunoVezoli *I need to to this with absolutely no library function* -- So nothing stops you from creating your own library of functions, i.e. your own `strcpy`, etc.  Then use those in the larger program instead of trying to shoehorn all of this inside of the `deleteLand` function.

Comment: @TomKarzes actually the project has a framework which takes care of seeing if it works so I wouldn't know much but I think you are right, it isn't a true 2d array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes I actually had to create my own strLengtg and strcopy but still I can't copy the parameter into a different place in the memory.

Comment: @BrunoVezoli You are not copying a matrix.  All you're doing in your code is copying a pointer value.  To actually copy the matrix (i.e., the data), you have to allocate a brand new matrix, and copy row by row, the data from the source matrix to the destination matrix.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes I know, that aux variable is useless. The problem is that if I try to declare something like char** mat = new char[col][row] the compiler gives an error

Comment: @BrunoVezoli Please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425126/dynamic-allocation-of-two-dimensional-array-c/27425293#27425293)  You should be encapsulating the code to create a 2 dimensional, dynamic array.  Also is this C or C++?

Comment: The C syntax for declaring `aux` as a 2D array of `char` would be `char aux[row][col];`.  C has no `new` operator -- that's a C++ thing.  Of course, you've tagged C++ too, so which language are you actually using?  They are different.

Comment: By the way, do you mean you *cannot* modify the original matrix?  If, as you actually wrote, you *can* modify it, then there probably is no advantage in making a copy.

Comment: I believe I can use both C and C++, I wasn't really though either of them to be honest I just infer them. We weren't thought since we come from a Java background. My teachers at college assume we just have to adapt. Excuse me if I'm being ignorant but I believe I can use both right? Like this is C syntax with all the pointers but I can also mix some C++ new. Am I wrong saying this?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can actually do whatever I want with the matrix inside but it needs to come out as it came in. The homework here is to solve the problems however you can actually but following pre and post conditions set in the letter

Comment: `char (*arr)[COLS]` is a "pointer to array of `char`" (equivalent to `char *p` which is a "pointer to `char`"). You can use it to point to the first element of an array. Now think for yourself what the first element of such an array would be. Note that you can copy such an array with a single `memcpy` call. The same for `malloc` and `free`. `COLS` can be a local variable or a macro, e.g. `#define COLS 100`.

Comment: @Olaf That initialization doesn't work for me since the compiler tells me that cols should be of constant value while here it is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Sure, because the compiler does not see the `col` argument when the array is declared. You have to move the array declaration past `col` (better: to the end): `f(int r, int c, int a[r][c])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy an array (data from an array), you'd need to allocate space for it. After using the copy you should free the memory.

---

I suppose the only reason to copy the data in this case is to restore the original data in `map`. If so, much better solution would be to use another letter, say 'B', to mask visited islands in `deleteLand`. Then after you are done, you can quickly restore the original map changing all B's to T's. It avoids all the problems with allocating and deallocating memory.

**EDIT**: I had to remove the actual code, which was in C++, since the tag C++ was removed in the meantime.

Comment: Well that changing to 'B' is a great way to solve all the problems here. I just finished creating my method with the suggestions from @PaulMcKenzie. Thanks a lot Paul I'll post my solution just in case

Comment: The question is tagged C.

Comment: @Olaf it was tagged c++ when I was writing this comment. Should I edit it?

Comment: @Olaf Was this the reason of downvoting me?

Comment: Don't accuse someone DVing without proof. 1) It is the person's right to do if she thinks it is not useful 2) There is no necessary correlation between a DV and a comment.

Comment: Sorry for that, didn't want to accuse anyone. I was just confused, because OP clearly stated in comments C++ was alright and his own answer, which also uses operator new, didn't get that attention.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in a comment I could fix the problem with the help of PaulMcKenie, I'll post the code just in case it's useful for anyone.

```
char** copyMatrix(char ** mat, int cols) {
char** newMat = new char*[cols];
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    newMat[i] = copyStr(mat[i]);
}
return newMat;
}
```

And, as I mentioned before I can't use library functions so I'll also post copyStr:

```
char* copyStr(char* string) {
char* copia = new char[strLen(string)];
int i = 0;
while (*string) {
    copia[i] = *string;
    *string++;
    i++;
}
copia[i] = *string;
return copia;
}
```